# Add column to Workflow Status page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-activity, state-machine

I have created a State Machine Workflow and I want to add another column on the Workflow Status page.

Currently there are `Assigned To`,  `Title`, `Due Date`, `Status`, `Related Content` and `Outcome`. I am trying to add another field named `Remarks`. How can this be accomplished? I found a link to it before but cannot recall how to add the Column field. Also, can this be done without modifying the `elments.xml`?

I thought it was a way to add a task list column or content type

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

The answers I researched only provided creating a copy of the WrkStat.aspx page in the 14 HIVE which is not best practice. What I came up with was to create a LogHistoryEvent which creates a comment for each state so that I can track the user who approved a certain task